# Titanium view being pushed up when keyboard shows up

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I have a window (vertical layout) that looks like this:

```
-Window
   -View1
   -View2
   -ScrollView1
   -ScrollView2
       -TextArea (contained in the scrollView2)
```

When I focus in on the textarea the keyboard comes up, but when this happens View1 and View2 scroll up and out of the window. So it looks like this now:

```
-Window
   -ScrollView1
   -ScrollView2
      -Textarea
   -Keyboard
```

I need these two views to stay put and only have the content inside scrollView1 and scrollView2 ( scrollView2 because it contains the textarea and if it is not in a scrollView the keyboard overlaps the textarea so users can't see what they are typing ). How to stop View1 and View2 from being pushed up? I thought if I made View1 and View2 with a top property of 0 that they would always stay put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using following in your manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

like this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity.YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_subscription_setup"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

there are various values like adjustPan, adjustResize etc etc. Try them out to see what works best for your situation.