# Screen jumps when calling a dialogfragment

Tags: android, animation, datepicker, android-fragmentactivity, dialogfragment

I am calling a dialogfragment from a FragmentActivity which I am using the dialogfragment as a datepicker. I have an edittext box that fires the onFocusChangedListener to call the dialogfragment.  Everything loads fine, except that the dialog and activity "jump" up then settle into place.  I am fairly new to android programming and I havent told it to do anything but open the datepicker.  There is no custom theme or style.

Im posting from my phone right now, so its hard to paste code.

Comment: hope this helps, check my answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590078/titanium-view-being-pushed-up-when-keyboard-shows-up/23590138#23590138)

Comment: That didnt work.  I tried adjustPan, adjustNothing.  It only slowed it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly happening because Android try to opens the keyboard when the `EditText`is clicked.

Insated in your XML add

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to the `EditText` and move the code from `onFocusChangedListener` to `onClickListener`